# How do you create a Windows service account in Amazon web services?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services

I am having trouble with one of my systems because a service doesn't behave well if it runs as LocalSystem so i want to create a service account. Is ti possible to create one in amazon without ADFS, where our servers are?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the usual DOS commands to create a local user and assign the user's credentials for your given service:

For e.g, create a user:

> net user user1 P@ssw0rd /add

Make sure you user has service logon rights:

> ntrights.exe -U user1 +r SeServiceLogonRight

Update your service's logon credentials to use this user:

> sc config YouServiceName obj= user1  password= P@ssw0rd